# Keyboard Repeat Delay turned on unexpectedly

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, delay, keylistener, key-bindings

I'm relatively new to java and
I'm making a game that involves moving an object with the arrow keys (the longer you hold the faster it goes).

Here is the code for these movements (I'm using a keylistener):

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int c = e.getKeyCode();

        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_A||c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            PacMan.velX -= PacMan.speed;
            PacMan.move = true;
            //PacMan.velY = 0;
            System.out.println("LEFT");
        }
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_D||c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            PacMan.velX += PacMan.speed;
            PacMan.move = true;
            //PacMan.velY = 0;
            System.out.println("RIGHT");
        }
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_W||c == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            PacMan.velY -= PacMan.speed;
            PacMan.move = true;
            //PacMan.velX = 0;
            System.out.println("UP");
        }
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_S||c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            PacMan.velY += PacMan.speed;
            PacMan.move = true;
            //PacMan.velX = 0;
            System.out.println("DOWN");
        }
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
            if(Main.pause == false){Main.pause = true;Main.move = true;}
            else if (Main.pause == true){Main.pause = false;Main.move = false;}
            System.out.println("Pause");
        }
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_R){
            Levels.setLevel();
        }
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_E){
            if(nextLevel){nextLevel = false;
            Levels.setLevel();}
        }

        Main.start = true;  

}
```

This worked fine, until I moved to Windows 8 (from windows xp). Now whenever I hold an arrow key, the keyboard repeat delay rate is turned on. So the object will move 1 step then pause, then the other steps kick in (just like when you hold a letter when typing in a text field).

I want the keyboard repeat delay off for this game, I'm not sure what to do.
Also I'd like to do be able to hold more than one key at a time (so it could go diagonally).

I attempted to understand KeyBindings but had trouble doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about changing keyboard repeat delay from code but what one thing you could do is start the processing (increasing or decreasing the speed) on keydown event and stop it on keyupevent. That way you won't be dependent on the keyboard rate delay.

You could have a look at - http://www.gamedev.net/topic/91523-changing-the-typematic-rate-delay/

A little different problem but the same solution.

Comment: Thanks, that's something I may do. I hope there is a way to resolve my specific problem, surely there is a way to fix this. I'll wait for other people to answer :)

Comment: okk :) if u later use what i suggested then mark above an answer. :)